# If $\sigma (T)'\subseteq \{ 0\} \ \ \forall T $ then are $T$s compact?

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory, compact-operators

In the book: "spectral theory of operators on Hilbert spaces, Carlos. S., (2012). page(46)." it has written:

[image]

> Is the converse of this theorem  true? Namely if for every operator
>   $T\in A(\text{a C}^*-\text{subalgebra of}\ B(H))$ we have $\sigma(T)'\subseteq \{0\} $, can we
>   imply $A\subseteq K(H)$?

Comment: Do not change your question after getting an answer.  Instead, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For instance, if $A$ consists just of scalar multiples of the identity, then the spectrum of every element of $A$ is a single point but $A\not\subseteq K(H)$.